# How to remove [ ] brackets from around text which inserted after export in csv file using PHPExcel

Tags: phpexcel

I export the report using PHPExcel into CSV file but it adds the [] around the text which is like `Spring - Full Semester, Fall - Full Semester, Summer - Summer Semester` in report column after export it reflects to `[Spring - Full Semester, Fall - Full Semester, Summer - Summer Semester]` So please help me in I do not want these kind of brackets around text block after export.

Comment: PHPExcel doesn't put any square brackets around the data, so the brackets must be there before that; but perhaps consider using [trim()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)?

Comment: Ok, I will try this.

Comment: One thing I have to explain that I am fetching the records from zoho CRM in which that text does not contains the brackets.

Comment: You can explain as much as you like, but I can assure you that the braces aren't being added by PHPExcel, so they're being added somewhere between zoho and your insertion of the data into PHPExcel, which means they're being added somewhere in your code.... are you trying to json_encode anything?

Comment: Although if all you're doing is creating a csv file, then it's a lot more efficient to use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function than a complex library like PHPExcel

Comment: Yes I am using json_decode.